# Problem with c# timer

Tags: c#

I have a method that I want to call a method (will mention as myFanc) in seperated thread every 3 seconds

The code below can easly do it,

```
 Timer myTimer = new Timer();
 myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler( myFanc );
 myTimer.Interval = 3000;
 myTimer.Start();
```

The code above may cause myFanc to be called while another call to myFanc isn't finished yet

My problem is that I also want myFanc to finished before I will call her agian, so basically I want to call the method in seperated thread every 3 seconds after myFanc is finished, how can I do it?

I don't mind if the solution won't use Timer class, I just want this behavior to work..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `AutoReset` property of your timer to false, then, at the end of your event handler (i.e. "myFanc"), call the `Start` method of your timer again.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of myFunc put this

```
myTimer.Enabled = false;
```

and at the end when it is finished put this

```
myTimer.Enabled = true;
```

It will cause that you will temporairly disable the Timer while function is executing

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a timer, loop in the thread calling "myfanc" and use

```
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

to insert the desired delay.

Comment: @Delashmate: if you are indeed using different threads already, I second this suggestion - sleeping the second thread is the preferred way of handling the delay then.

Comment: @Delashmate: On what reasoning? This is an appropriate use of thread.sleep

Comment: @Jim, is Thread.Sleep consuming cpu? if so then it isn't elegant solution

Comment: Thread.Sleep suspend the thread, thus it does not consume CPU

Comment: @Felice, from what I know the OS isn't using event in Thread.Sleep, it just keep checking, can I continue, can I continue, and so on until the time will pass

Comment: @Delashmate event has nothing to do with Thread.Sleep. You can check that by suspending a thread for say, ten seconds ( 10000 ) the CPU comsumption of your process is 0...

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I used - thanks to Jim

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;

class myApp
{
    public static void Main()
{
      System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
      myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler( myFanc );
      myTimer.Interval = 1000;
      myTimer.AutoReset = false;
      myTimer.Start();

      while ( Console.Read() != 'q' )
      {
          ;    // do nothing...
      }
    }

public static void myFanc(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Write("\r{0}", DateTime.Now);

    Thread.Sleep(3000); //the sleep here is just to test the method, wait to be finished before another call the myFanc method is being performed
    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myFanc);
    myTimer.Interval = 1000;
    myTimer.AutoReset = false;
    myTimer.Start();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

2 methods than I can think of right now

1. Stop and start the timer inside the myFanc method This ensures 3 seconds between each run
2. Wrap your code in myFanc inside a lock, this will just skip a turn if it's not finished.

Make sure you use the correct timer.. system.threading.timer is a seperate thread. The timer class in windows.forms (or something like that) isn't

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread and Thread.Sleep(x) like so

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myTimer));
thread.Start();


void myTimer()
{
    while (!exit)
    {
        myFunc();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: why? Its perfectly suited to introducing lag like as required here